# How many non-decreasing sequences of $7$ decimal digits are there?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many non-decreasing sequences of $7$ decimal digits are there?
>   ($3334559$  and $0223448$ are two examples).

Solution:

> If we add a $0$ to the beginning and a $9$ to the end, every sequence
>   of $7$ nondecreasing decimal digits defines a unique sequence of $8$
>   non-negative gaps which must sum to $9$ (e.g. for $3334559$ the gaps are
>   $3+0+0+1+1+0+4+0 = 9$, and for $0223448$ the gaps are $0+2+0+1+1+0+4+1
>   = 9$). We need $7$ separators to count the partitions (the digits themselves separate the gaps), and we then find that there are
>   $\binom{9+7}{7} =  11,440$ of them.

I am having some trouble in understanding the very first statement of this solution, in spite of the given example. I just couldn't understand what they exactly meant there. Could anybody explain this to me more lucidly?

However,the second sentence is consistent to the [stars and bars idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) and I have no doubt in understanding it.

PS:This is the #$6$ problem from [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/courses/combinatorics-the-fine-art-of-counting/assignments/solutions_5.pdf).

---

**Added:**

I guess now I have understood the trick, but this seems something new to me. I was wondering how to approach this problem in different way? Any ideas?

Comment: Re your addendum, I would have approached the problem as follows: I have ten buckets, labeled 0 through 9, and 7 balls. How many different ways are there of placing the balls in the buckets? It's still stars and bars (this time 9 bars and 7 stars) but maybe is a more intuitive approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have seven digits $d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5 d_6 d_7$ and pad it with 0 and 9 as indicated ($0d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5 d_6 d_79)$, you can look at the eight differences of consecutive digits (I have no idea why the author called them "gaps," which may be the source of confusion)
$$\begin{align*}d_1 &- 0\\
d_2 &- d_1\\
d_3 &- d_2,\end{align*}$$
and so on. Since the digits are nondecreasing each of these differences is nonnegative, and their sum telescopes leaving 9:
$$9-d_7 + d_7 - d_6 + \ldots + d_2 - d_1 + d_1 - 0 = 9-0 = 9.$$

The number of ways to pick eight nonnegative numbers that sum to 9 is then the "stars and bars" problem, with 9 stars and 7 bars.

Comment: Aha,thanks,and I agree "gaps" made things confusing for me ...however the overall solving trick seems to be a very good one!

Comment: Do you have any idea about why such a choice of padding?I mean is this problem specific or something that is more common?

Comment: @FoolForMath:  This choice of padding gives known values to the ends, reducing it to a known problem.  Alternately you could do it for each possibility of $d_1$ and $d_7$, but there are a bunch of cases.